# Как удалить символ char из его же массива

Tags: c++, char

Всем привет. Есть такая задача : В Входном файле дается никнейм, нам надо, чтобы в таблице сортировки по имени этот ник стоял как можно ниже, притом удалить можно только один символ. Мой код:

```
ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");

string str;
char ch[str.size()],temp;
in >> str;

strcpy(ch, str.c_str());

temp=ch[0];             
for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++){  
if(ch[i] > temp){
delete ch[i];
break;
}   
else temp=ch[i];
}
string str2=ch;
out << str2;
```

Мы смотрим, если второй символ ниже в алфавите первого, мы первый удаляем
Компилятор указывает на одну единственную ошибку - delete ch[i];
Eroor:type 'char' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
Как быть?

Comment: Ну во-первых `char ch[str.size()]` массивы с автоматическим хранением не являются стандартной фичей языка. Во-вторых `delete ch[i];` некорректно, так как аргумент не является указателем, выделенным при помощи `new`. Под "удалить" тут явно понимается переместить символы после `i`-го на один назад.

Comment: ясно  сказано, что ожидается указатель...  Вы пытетесь удалять значение

Comment: приведите пример входных и выходных данных, а то ничего не понятно

Comment: @Hovsepyan smith-smth

Comment: практически удаляете  самый меньший символ в строке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete` не из той оперы...

Ваше `delete ch[i];` следует развернуть в

```
for(int j = i+1; ch[j-1] = ch[j]; ++j);
```

Или воспользоваться `memmove()`.

Answer (score 0):

Слушайте, а что вы сдесь вообще делаете? Вот у вас есть некая переменная str, которая, как можно заключить из метода c_str() имеет тип std::string. Так зачем вы используете массив char? Не поймите меня неверно, я люблю Си, но вот зачем использовать функции из cstring в перемешку с классом string? Тем более что вы это делаете не верно. И раз уж у вас вопрос с меткой с++, то порекомендую сделать все через string (и правильно). Как то так:

```
ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt"); 
std::string str;
// сдесь вы вообще брали у str size, который равен 0 на данный момент
in >> str; 
// две строки сдесь вообще не нужны - у вас дублирование данных
// далее вы в вопросе указали что нужно удалить первый символ, если он меньше второго, но почему то обходите всю строку, вместо того, чтобы сделать так:
if (str[0] < str[1]) 
  str.erase(str.begin());
else 
  str.erase(1);
out << str;
```

Обратите внимание, что не только код сократился, но и количество переменных тоже сократилось. Ровно до одной.